# Enable/disable Force Field function of keyframe

Tags: particles, force-fields

So I have a simulation where I want some force fields to be working from frame X to frame Y, with the rest of the frames performing other types of simulations... is there a way to achieve this, including via python scripting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are in blender 2.8, you can click the small circle next to the settings you are trying to animate (frame X), which will make it go brown, then go to frame Y and change the value and then click the diamond shape to lock the setting